It was not possible to find any compatible framework version The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '6.0.0' was not found
I've dotnet core 3.1 application
but when I'm tring to run it using vs code
I'm facing this issue
024-04-13 06:39:39.059 [info] It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '6.0.0' was not found.

The following frameworks were found:
3.1.32 at [/home/tariq/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.
The specified framework can be found at:

https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=6.0.0&arch=x64&rid=ubuntu.22.04-x64

2024-04-13 06:39:39.380 [info] Project system initialization finished. 0 project(s) are loaded, and 1 failed to load.
I had installed vs code extensions C# and C# dev kit by microsoft
also when I'm trying to run the code by f5
I'm facing this erorr
No C# project is currently loaded. Please create a C# project in order to debug.

from dev kit
